# addeventlistener not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
(function() {
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
var myFunction = function()
{
    alert("hello");
    var el = this;
    var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
    var tr = st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
     st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
     "Either no transform set, or browser doesn't do getComputedStyle";
     console.log(tr);
}

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, true);
}
})();



<div class="data">data1</div>
<div class="data">data2</div>
<div class="data">data3</div>
<div class="data">data4</div>
```

I am using pure javascript to add event listener to the div .

The add event listener not working

Some guys said to me to add the event listener at window.load but i am getting my dom objects here in this javascript.
Any help?

Comment: the event listener works for me, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1n546pkx/ please clarify what is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your code. you just need to put your code below the DOM.

> Best place to add your script is before the end of body tag. Use external script files instead of internal of script.

For example only I am using script inside html. You should use script as external file which is best practice.

Working Code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="data">data1</div>
    <div class="data">data2</div>
    <div class="data">data3</div>
    <div class="data">data4</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  (function() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
    var myFunction = function()
    {
        alert("hello");
        var el = this;
        var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
        var tr = st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
        st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
        "Either no transform set, or browser doesn't do getComputedStyle";
       console.log(tr);
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, true);
  }
  })();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

DOMContentLoaded event will execute your code after DOM is loaded and parsed. so it will not give error.

Comment: yes , it worked , but can u tell me why var var `var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('data');` is giving me dom objects, then

Comment: It is a selector method it will return dom objects only. see specification for more detail - https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-getelementsbyclassname

Comment: no no no , i want to ask why it returned the dom object on calling the script before the html

Comment: it is about DOM parsing. your script run first and dom parsing happens later. so it will not get DOM objects if you write script above the DOM elements. I will edit my answer to make it more correct

Answer (score 1):

Your code works. You must run your script after DOM is loaded, or you must write
`DOMContentLoaded` eventListener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    (function() {
        var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('data');
        var myFunction = function()
        {
            //.... Your code
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
            divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, true);
        }
    })();
});
```